# Installing Ubuntu 12.04 without installing Grub

Tags: 12.04, grub2, system-installation, live-cd

Using the Ubuntu 12.04 Live CD, is possible not to install Grub? In previous versions, there was a checkbox called something like "skip grub installation", now in 12.04 this checkbox isn't there any more.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think I have any idea what you are asking. Grub is always part of an Ubuntu installation. Precisely what are you trying to do and how? Is your question something to do with an existing installation of a different operating system, if so, what is it. Please say what you have already and what you expect to be able to do.

Comment: In previous versions of ubuntu (up to 11.04 I think) when installing the system there was a checkbox called something like "skip grub installation", now in 12.04 these checkbox there isn't any more

Comment: For installs that don't fit the streamlined approach of the live-cd, you need to use the alternate iso. Works like a charm, just not so pretty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

It has been many years since the bulk of this answer was the *correct* answer.

The solution now is to start Ubuntu from a live disc and use the terminal to invoke Ubiquity as follows:

```
ubiquity --no-bootloader
```

You can alternatively use the short form like this:

```
ubiquity -b
```

### Old answer

The following is no longer valid, but I will preserve it as it was originally when the question was asked and it is possible somebody may want to do this with Ubuntu <= 12.04

Installing GRUB is the usually the best way to go, whether or not you're dual-booting, but to install Ubuntu 12.04 without GRUB, download the alternate CD for [x86](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-i386.iso) or [AMD64](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-amd64.iso).

Run the install as normal, after the `Select and install software` step, the installer will run `Install the GRUB boot loader on a hard disk`. It will tell you what other operating systems, if any that it's found, and ask if it should install, at this point, choose `Go Back`, then in the installer menu that appears next, choose `Continue without boot loader`.

Please be aware that after installation you will have to configure your existing boot loader before you can boot your new installation of Ubuntu.

Comment: 12.10 and higher have no alternate CD. Workaround: download an older alternate CD, and do `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` after reboot. That will upgrade the system to the latest version.

Comment: `apt-get dist-upgrade` only upgrades packages within a specific Ubuntu release.

Comment: Use the answer below.  This should not be the solved answer

Comment: @BhikkhuSubhuti this was correct at the time it was posted (7 years ago!), but unfortunately is no longer valid. I had a note at the bottom for new versions, but I have now moved it to the top so that the text people see first in the answer is the current method.

Thanks for bringing it to my attention, I had completely forgotten about this answer

Answer (score 16):

Run the regular LiveCD and open a terminal. Run either `ubiquity -b` or `ubiquity --no-bootloader`.

Comment: `man ubiquity` does not mention that option on 12.10, however `ubiquity --help` does. I guess it is a lack in the manual.

Answer (score 2):

You can also open a terminal after booting the LiveCD and launch ubiquity with a proper switch, that disables GRUB installation. I forgot what it was called but ubiquity --help will tell you :) That worked for me, when I was trying to setup Ubuntu on my fakeraid PC and GRUB kept going belly-up.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and type `ubiquity -b` all lower letters

This will open the installer and will install ubuntu with out the ubuntu bootloader known as grub,

- Note : If you don't install Ubuntu's boot loader "Grub" you wont be able to boot Ubuntu, I've tried installing Ubuntu side by side windows, using the above step, then installing EasyBCD, then selecting "Grub 2" as the boot loader for the Ubuntu Part, I rebooted, to find I still could not boot in to Ubuntu with out Ubuntu having "Grub" within it's part, so I do NOT recommend following the above step, unless you know how to get around this, in which case, please post the magic bellow

Comment: You can boot Ubuntu, even without the default Ubuntu's GRUB by installing [grub2win](https://sourceforge.net/projects/grub2win) on Windows. It does make a GRUB entry inside Windows' BCD. What did you only need to do is to make an entry to your Ubuntu installation, and points the entry to the partition where you install Ubuntu.

Comment: If you have another linux aleady installed (two or three os's).  You can do sudo update-grub and it will run the os prober for you.