# Installing Ubuntu desktop cd 12.04.3-32bit without installing Grub

Tags: installation, grub2, ubiquity

I want to install Ubuntu desktop 12.04.3-32bit without installing grub.i have googled for the same and found ([Installing Ubuntu 12.04 without installing Grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132116/installing-ubuntu-12-04-without-installing-grub)) ,tried the same like below but it does not help

linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity     **ubiquity --no-bootloader** quiet splash --

I can able to achieve the same with alternate cd image with preseed and desktop image with preseed but am in a position that i have to achieve desktop image without preseed.

Please help me on this

Regards
Senthil

Comment: Why do you want to not instal grub? Without it you can't load Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Its impossible Grub is required to load Ubuntu or any other operating system that uses Grub without it your computer simply will NOT boot-up. It's the same with windows you must have a copy of the MBR, same as grub but for windows installed or the computer will not detect you have an operating system installed.

Comment: I understand that i can't boot Ubuntu without grub.actually am trying to install 12.04.3-32bit on Intel baytrail,EFI based hardware.32bit Ubuntu does not support EFI so it throws"Failed to install grub-efi to /target/..."error.I have overcome from this issue by customizing 32bit ISO using Ubuntu-builder.In that am keeping efi part of the ubuntu-builder file system so during installation,"efi" will be copied to the system /boot folder.basically i wanted to skip "Failed to install..."error.hence i decided,i can suppress the error by skipping grub installation.Hope you are clear on my issue now.

Comment: Did the computer you are using come with Windows 8? If it did you will have to use a 64bit version of Ubuntu. This may help with the error you are getting if it is a 64bit Intel.

Comment: Hardware didn't come with Windows8.It has got 32bit version of EFI(BIOS) so i have to install 32bit version of Ubuntu only