# How to run multiple Ubuntu 18.x with separate partition encryption and UEFI/Secure Boot?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, encryption, luks, refind

To have a clear separation of concerns for different tasks (work, open source programming, gaming), without investing in multiple computers, I prefer installing parallel operating systems on separately encrypted partitions.

Wishlist, goals:

- Use a single machine with a single hard drive.
- Use [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) with [Secure Boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Secure_boot).
- Install multiple, highly separated instances of Linux in parallel.

  - Separately encrypted partitions to ensure no (easy) access to the disks of other instances.
  - Keeps own software, settings, and home folders.
  - Currently [Ubuntu 18.x Desktop](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).
  - Could be other distributions, but that's not covered here.
- Install one instance of Windows.

  - Not the main focus.
  - Currently [Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).
- Optionally use other partitions or disks for general (shared) storage.

  - Not covered here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used the below steps to set up three separate Ubuntu systems on one machine. Works great!

### Ideas

- Use [`refind`](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) rather than [`grub`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) to manage system selection during UEFI/Secure Boot.
- Don't use a separate `/boot` partition per Linux instance. Let [`refind` boot the kernel directly](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/linux.html) from the [EFI system partition (ESP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition).
- Set up [Linux Unified Key Setup (LUKS)](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/blob/master/README.md) from the Ubuntu installer.
- Note that the current solution doesn't encrypt the kernel files, as booting directly to encrypted disks is not supported by `refind`.

### Overview

- Obviously create multiple backups of any valuable data beforehand. Changing the boot procedure, formatting disks, enabling encryption, etcetera can be hazardous and care needs to be taken.
- Install Windows first.

  - Seems to be a general recommendation, though should matter less with UEFI.
  - It will prepare the GPT and ESP, this can also be done manually using [GNOME Partition Editor](https://gparted.sourceforge.io/) from the Ubuntu USB/DVD.
  - The ESP created by the Windows installer might not be big enough, depending on the number of Ubuntu instances and kernel sizes. 512 MB seems enough for 2 Ubuntu-instances, but 1 GB would be safer and allow more instances.
- Install `refind` and make sure it boots with Secure Boot.
- For each desired Ubuntu system instance:

  - Run the default Ubuntu installer from USB or DVD.
  - Select the option "Something else" to manually set up encryption and select partitions.
  - Don't reboot after the installation, but stay to setup the `refind` boot process.
- Over time, perform maintenance tasks if there are kernel or driver updates.

---

### Per-instance installation

Assumes that the [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) and the ESP has been set up by the Windows installer, and that there are additional partitions(s) or empty disk space for the Ubuntu instance(s).

#### Partition paths and names

For consistency I'll use this partition path naming below. Paths will be different on your system, and will vary by instance, so please keep notes.

- `/dev/nvme0n1p11` is your ESP.
- `/dev/nvme0n1p22` is your temporary `/boot` partition.
- `/dev/nvme0n1p33` is your per-instance "physical volume for encryption" (locked) root `/` partition.
- `/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p33_crypt` is your (unlocked) root `/` partition.

#### Partition and install a new (additional) Ubuntu instance

1. Get Ubuntu on USB or DVD, boot it selecting "Try out Ubuntu".
2. Open a terminal to update and start the installer.

   ```
   sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade -y
   ubiquity --no-bootloader
   ```
3. When asked about installation type (co-existing with other operating systems) and disk formatting/partitioning, select "Something else" to see a list of disks and partitions.
4. Find the partition with type `efi`, the ESP.

   - On my system this is `/dev/nvme0n1p11`.
   - Make a note of the partition path name as you'll need it below.
   - Check that it has at least 200 MB free before continuing, as it will be needed for the new instance kernel.
5. Select or create a boot partition.

   - On my system this is `/dev/nvme0n1p22`.
   - Make a note of the boot partition path name as you'll need it below.
   - Will be reused for subsequent Ubuntu instance installations.
   - Create or select a small (maximum 512 MB) partition.
   - Erase/format as EXT4.
   - Click "change" and mount it as `/boot`.
6. Select or create a root partition for Ubuntu.

   - On my system this is `/dev/nvme0n1p33`.
   - Make a note of the root partition path name as you'll need it below.
   - It will be erased.
   - 5 GB for minimal, 25+ GB for a full installation.
   - Click "change" and make it an "physical volume for encryption".
   - Choose a password which is not the same as for the other instances.
7. Find the new, unlocked partition ending with `_crypt`.

   - On my system this is `/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p33_crypt`.
   - Change the mount point to root `/`.
8. Let the installer finish, but do not reboot at the end by selecting "Continue testing".

#### Set up `refind` for the new instance.

1. Enter `chroot` to the new operating system to make more changes.

   ```
   # NOTE: create temporary mount directories.
   sudo mkdir /mnt/bootpartition /mnt/ospartition

   # NOTE: Mount the newly created encrypted partition.
   sudo mount -o subvol=@ /dev/mapper/nvme0n1p33_crypt /mnt/ospartition
   sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p22 /mnt/bootpartition

   # NOTE: Copy the boot files into the encrypted partition.
   # NOTE: Watch those trailing slashes! rsync is very sensitive to them.
   sudo rsync -aXAH /mnt/bootpartition/ /mnt/ospartition/boot/

   sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p11 /mnt/ospartition/boot/efi
   sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/ospartition/dev
   sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/ospartition/proc
   sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/ospartition/sys

   # NOTE: change root to the newly installed Ubuntu.
   sudo chroot /mnt/ospartition
   ```
2. Edit `/etc/fstab` and comment out the line for `/boot`. The other entries are correct.
3. Optional: make other low-level system file changes, such as workarounds for broken drivers<sup>1</sup>.
4. Create an EFI-bootable copy of the [kernel (`vmlinuz`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vmlinux) and the [initial ramdisk (`initrd`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_ramdisk) for `refind`. Remember to replace `ubuntu-instance` with something of our own. I use "ubuntu-work" and similar. Do not use just "ubuntu" as it might get overwritten by the Ubuntu installer.

   ```
   # NOTE: Choose your own per-instance directory name.
   sudo mkdir /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu-instance/
   sudo cp /boot/vmlinuz* /boot/initrd* /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu-instance/
   ```
5. Look for `/dev/nvme0n1p33`, the physical volume for encryption for this instance. Make a note of (or copy to the clipboard) the UUID (but not the PARTUUID).

   ```
   sudo blkid
   ```
6. Prepare `refind`'s Ubuntu instance kernel boot options for the encrypted partition in `refind_linux.conf`. Create `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu-instance/refind_linux.conf` from the below template, but with your path and UUID.

   ```
   "Boot with standard options"  "root=/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p33_crypt cryptdevice=UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx:nvme0n1p33_crypt ro quiet splash"
   "Boot to single-user mode"    "root=/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p33_crypt cryptdevice=UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx:nvme0n1p33_crypt ro single"
   "Boot with minimal options"   "root=/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p33_crypt cryptdevice=UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx:nvme0n1p33_crypt ro"
   ```
7. Exit `chroot` and reboot. Remember to select the new kernel in `refind`.

   ```
   exit
   sudo reboot
   ```

#### Cleanup

Optional. This will remove unused boot options in `refind`. I like to keep them around as a backup until the system is stable.

- Remove any leftover shared Ubuntu Grub bootloader.

  ```
  # NOTE: The shared Ubuntu Grub EFI loader might be leftover from previous installations.
  #sudo rm -r /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/
  ```
- Remove files from the unused boot partition.

  ```
  # NOTE: Optionally clean up files from the Ubuntu installer.
  #sudo mkdir /mnt/bootpartition
  #sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p22 /mnt/bootpartition
  #sudo rm -r /mnt/bootpartition/*
  ```

---

### Maintenance after kernel or driver updates

As Ubuntu doesn't know about `refind`, kernel+driver updates require a manual copy step for vmlinuz+initrd.

- After installing updates, but before rebooting, copy the new vmlinuz+initrd from the encrypted `/boot` to the unencrypted ESP's `ubuntu-instance` like above.
- If you forget to do this, and the system broke or new drivers didn't load, boot either:

  - Single-user mode from `refind` by choosing custom boot options.
  - The Ubuntu installer USB/DVD, and mount to temporary locations:

    - The encrypted disk which contains `/boot`.
    - The ESP.
  - Copy the vmlinuz+initrd from your `/boot` to the ESP's `ubuntu-instance` like above.

### Future improvements

- If/when there are [EFI file system drivers](https://rodsbooks.com/refind/drivers.html) so `refind` can read encrypted LUKS partitions, investigate not keeping the kernels on the unencrypted ESP. This might greatly simplify the above setup.
- Running `ubiquity --no-bootloader` skips installing `shim-signed`, so third-party DKMS modules/drivers (nvidia etcetera) require manual signing for secure boot. This can be done using [`kmodsign` for `/lib/modules/x.y.z/updates/dkms/*.ko` after each kernel/driver update](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/Signing). A smoother alternative is to install `shim-signed` (including parts of `grub`), which does automatic signing. Perhaps there's an alternative which is less grubby?
- Figure out if kernel+driver updates can automatically trigger updating the per-instance ESP vmlinuz+initrd copy for `refind`.
- Improve temporary boot partition usage with one of:

  - Configure the temporary boot partition as encrypted swap space in each of the Linux instances.
  - Reusing the ESP for temporary `/boot` files. Didn't want the added risk of destroying the ESP by accidentally formatting it or similar, but might work just as well.

### Inspiration

Thank you!

- [@Aleksandr Dubinsky's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/801394) to "Ubuntu full disk encryption with encrypted /boot".
- [@StefK's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/148192) to "Installing Ubuntu 12.04 without installing Grub".
- [@Rod Smith's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/617112) to "How do I install two independent Ubuntu installations on a single hard drive with UEFI?"
- Many more answers, articles, documentation written by [Roderick W. Smith](https://www.rodsbooks.com/), who is the author of `refind`.
- Ubuntu's [installation documentation](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop) for desktop usage.

---

<sup>1</sup> This [Wayland plus Nvidia grapics driver problem](https://askubuntu.com/a/975098/78100) caught me. It causes a black screen after the disk has been unlocked. Luckily it's easy to fix and Wayland can be restored once [updated Nvidia drivers have been installed](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) -- just remember to copy the updated kernel+initrd to your ESP.

Comment: See also: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManualFullSystemEncryption/
Full-system encryption with manual control and dual-booting Paddy Landau
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2357627